# Has anyone ever tried to collect passwords and user logins from ssh-attacks?

Tags: ssh, honeypot

I guess it should be easily possible to open the ssh port with a fake ssh server and collect passes (I guess they aren't plain anymore and became hashes) and corresponding logins, e.g. a honey-pot. The idea behind that is to build a database and test my accounts on those. Has anyone done that already?

If you might wonder what benefit I would expect on testing my accounts with those passwords, I would argue that passwords might change during time and I could eventually anticipate a "successful" ssh-attack.

Comment: Ish.  I wrote a twitter bot that grabbed login attempts from denyhosts, and posted to twitter: https://twitter.com/#!/crackerwatch

Comment: What'd be the point?  There are many password lists available for download.  Just use those.

Comment: The gathered database would be very recent. Can you give good links to download recent lists? E.g. http://www.skullsecurity.org/wiki/index.php/Passwords seems just to provide lists to 2010..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, Stephen Murdoch at the University of Cambridge has done it, earlier this year.  You can read his results in the Security Research Group blog; the initial experiment is discussed [in this article](http://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/2012/01/06/brute-force-password-guessing-attempts-on-ssh/), and some more results appear [in this article](http://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/2012/01/25/observations-from-two-weeks-of-ssh-brute-force-attacks/).

My personal favourite bit was

> For example, there was a log-in attempt for the usernames “root” and “dark” with
> the password “ManualulIngineruluiMecanic”, which I think is Romanian
> for Handbook of Mechanical Engineering.
>
> Why would someone use this
> password, especially for the uncommon username “dark”? Is this book
> common in Romania; is it likely to be by the desk of a sys-admin (or
> hacker) trying to choose a password? Has the hacker found the password
> in use on another compromised system; is it the default password for
> anything?

Answer (score 4):

Since SSH attacks are dictionary-attacks with some flair, downloading a text file of a dictionary would provide you with a lot of potential passwords. It wouldn't hurt to set up a honeypot as that would provide you with more common passwords.

If you feel lazy however, you could download a plaintext of password dumps from major websites, as there are plenty of those around and (after filtering them for repeats) you should get a good database of commonly used passwords.

Fortunately, since human nature is a sluggish thing, you'll be good to go on that alone until people get better memory, or until someone invents a computer that doesn't need humans to input things.